# Does my code consuming more memory?

Tags: android, memory, live-wallpaper

I'm creating a live wallpaper. I don't know whether my code is consuming more memory or not. 
I checked through the adb logcat, it freed more memory frequently.

Is this normal for my code?
Link to my app:http://www.cybapps.com/temp/test.apk

This is my code:

```
public class CybWallpaper extends WallpaperService {

    int noofsnows=30;
    int x[]=new int[100],y[]=new int[100],speed[]=new int[100],nt=0;
    int isr=0;
    int scw,sch,snowsize=20;
    float cx[]=new float[100],cy[]=new float[100];
    Canvas dra;
    int temps[]=new int[100],tempcs[]=new int[100];
    boolean isft=true,isclicked=false;
    Bitmap snow,bg,ts,gift;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Bitmap te;
    boolean isrun;

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new Mywall();
    }
    public class Mywall extends Engine
    {

        Handler hand=new Handler();
        Random ran=new Random();
        Runnable iterate=new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                slower();
                drawframe();
            }

        };

        public void update()
        {
            //Background image
            settings=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            if(settings.getBoolean("cusimage", false))
            {

                File newImg=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/.cyb/livewallpaper.jpg");
                if(newImg.exists())
                {
                    bg=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/sdcard0/cyb/livewallpaper.jpg");
                }
                else
                    bg=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b1);
            }
            else
                bg=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b1);

            //Snows

            noofsnows=Integer.parseInt(settings.getString("noofsnow", "30"));
            for(int i=0;i<noofsnows&&isft;i++)
            {   
                x[i]=ran.nextInt(scw);
                y[i]=ran.nextInt(sch);
                temps[i]=(10+ran.nextInt(snowsize));
                tempcs[i]=(50+ran.nextInt(30));
                speed[i]=(4+ran.nextInt(4));
                cx[i]=-1;
                cy[i]=-1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
            snow=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s1);
            gift=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.g1);
            isft=true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
            isft=true;
            slower();
            drawframe();
        }

        protected void drawframe() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SurfaceHolder sh=getSurfaceHolder();
               dra = null;
               try {
                  dra = sh.lockCanvas();
                  if (dra != null) {


                        if(isft)
                        {
                            scw=dra.getWidth();
                            sch=dra.getHeight();
                            update();
                        }

                        isft=false;
                        dra.drawBitmap(bg, 0, 0, null);
                        drawsnow(dra,noofsnows);                    
                  }
               } finally {
                  if (dra != null)
                     sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(dra);
               }
        }

        private void drawsnow(Canvas dra,int n) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                te=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(snow, temps[i], temps[i], false);
                dra.drawBitmap(te, x[i]-(te.getWidth()/2), y[i]-(te.getHeight()/2), null);

                //If Clicked
                if(cx[i]!=-1&&cx[i]!=-1)
                {

                    ts=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(gift, tempcs[i], tempcs[i], false);
                    dra.drawBitmap(ts, cx[i]-(ts.getWidth()/2), cy[i]-(ts.getHeight()/2), null);
                    if(cy[i]<sch)
                        cy[i]+=speed[i];
                    else
                    {
                        cx[i]=-1;
                        cy[i]=-1;
                    }
                }


                //Snow to and fro
                if(isr==0&&x[i]!=140)
                    x[i]+=1;
                else
                    isr=1;

                if(isr==1&&x[i]!=120)
                    x[i]-=1;
                else
                    isr=0;

                if(y[i]<dra.getHeight())
                    y[i]+=speed[i];
                else
                {
                    y[i]=0;
                    x[i]=ran.nextInt(dra.getWidth());
                    temps[i]=10+ran.nextInt(snowsize);
                    speed[i]=4+ran.nextInt(2);
                }
            }

        }

        protected void slower() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hand.removeCallbacks(iterate);
             if (isrun) {
                hand.postDelayed(iterate, 1000/30);
             }

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            isrun=false;
            hand.removeCallbacks(iterate);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                isclicked=true;
                cx[nt]=event.getX();
                cy[nt]=event.getY();
                if(nt<=20)
                nt++;
                else
                    nt=0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
            isrun=visible;
            if(isrun)
            {
                isft=true;
                slower();
                drawframe();
            }
            else
            {
                hand.removeCallbacks(iterate);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: looks like you are decoding very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            te=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(snow, temps[i], temps[i], false);
```

You are repeatedly creating bitmaps without recycling them. You should not do that in the update function anyway.

```
// To be done once in onSurfaceCreated for instance
te=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(snow, temps[i], temps[i], false);

// Use your bitmap in update()

// To be done once in onSurfaceDestroyed for instance
te.recycle();
```

To change the size of the drawn bitmap, simply draw it scaled using the appropriate function of just by transforming the canvas with a matrix.

Comment: You're welcome. Accept answers which solved your problems (you can use the checkmark on the left to do that).